# Exchange 2010 Active Sync: Notes are lost

Tags: exchange, activesync

I have 1 user who sync his mailbox with BlackBerry Bold via BES and his iPhone 5s and iPad Air via ActiveSync. The main Client is Win7 with Outlook 2010. The user uses the notes feature in Outlook but the notes are lost randomly and i have to restore a backup.

Is there a way to log deletion or client access to the mailbox or a is there anywhere a detailed logfile of synchronization?

Comment: I'm almost certain it is something to do with BES. Can you possibly disable the BB as a test?

Comment: Error was a wrong configured retention policy, which was configured to delete all elements older than 2 years. Thanks for help